While installing win32api I got this error
Collecting pypiwin32
  Using cached pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 kB)
  Using cached pypiwin32-219.zip (4.8 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-oa3v6m4z/pypiwin32_71c718d15af441d6bc9956890d82e72f/setup.py", line 121
          print "Building pywin32", pywin32_version
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
      [end of output]


I noticed they had forgotten the parenthesis of print as they had put print "Building pywin32", pywin32_version  which should have been print("Building pywin32", pywin32_version)

I'm not exactly sure what pypiwin32 is - it was last updated in 2018, and has a project description of "UNKNOWN".  Obviously, this is not what you want to install!  Try installing pywin32 instead.
